# Find and Replace and attribute in XML file using libxml/xpath in C program

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2, xml-libxml

I have a xml file which has different sections and i need to 'rename' certain attributes appearing in this huge file (like find and replace with new name). All over i have used libxml and xpath to modify and satisfy other requirements, but for this one, i am not sure how this can done using libxml and xpath APIs. Please help.

e.g In the below file i need to find all 'ORANGE' string and replace it with say 'PURPLE' string. Please help..

```
<a>
    <my_section enum="ORANGE" name="blah"> </my_section> 
    <my_section enum="APPLE" name="blah blah"> </my_section>
    <my_section enum="ORANGE1" name="blah1"> </my_section>
    <your_section color="ORANGE" name="blah"> </your_section> 
    <another_section city="LONDON" blah="ORANGE"> </another_section>
    <any_section code="RED" age="ORANGE"> </any_section> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know XPath and how complicated it can be... but, maybe the solution to this problem is just a simple string replace? But maybe there are scenarios that I am not thinking of that you are not showing here this does not match for.

But if you really want to do it through xpath

```
//*[@*='ORANGE']
```

Selects all elements that contain an attribute with value orange

```
//*[@*='ORANGE']/@*[string()='ORANGE']
```

Gets you only the attributes

Comment: So, are you suggesting, i can just write a regular C function to find and replace the string in a given file?. Probably i can do that as a last option. I had to do lot of manipulation in this file, like removing sections, merging children from one section to another..all i could achieve by libxml/xpath. For this one also, i thought xpath provides some technique which i can use..

Comment: Thanks!!. Definitely helps. Using your solution, I am now able to collect all the nodes which has this required string as one of its attribute. But In one node, the attribute name could be 'enum' and in another node the attribute name could be 'color'. So replacing the string is still a bit of challenge now.

Comment: Doesn't the 2nd xpath I placed help with that? That one should return only the attributes that have the value you seek?

Comment: Dont use the first XPath i posted, that was purely to help you understand what the 2nd one does. The 2nd one returns a list of the attributes directly. Not the elements. I do not know much of C. But in C# i have 3 types of objects, XElement, XAttribute and XNodes. In this case I think you are using the C equivalent of XNode, so I'd suggest directly setting its text, or value.

Comment: Got it!. The first one itself returns the parent nodes. I have only two different type of 'attribute' types (enum and color). So I look for the node->name, if its enum, it set property for enum with new value, else it to it for 'color' attrib. My only intension was not to hard code looking for this particular 'attrtib' type. But i am ok to proceed with this solution for now. Thanks a lot for your kind help Davey van Tilburg

Comment: No problem! Very glad i could help you! :) Please do mark my response as answer if you don't mind. It helps me building some rep ^^